# Schizophrenia : Need a professional opinion

Tags: schizophrenia

In April 2017, My younger left the house without informing anyone. It was very hot summer here in India. Whole afternoon, he walked alone. When he left he took no money, no phone and anything. Somehow, When we got him back he told us that "I left home searching the god".

After few days, we told him to write about his feelings, why he left and how is he feeling now. I will attach the image of his writing. He is 16 years old.

Our psychologist told he is suffering from Schizo thought disorder. I want professional opinion based on his writing. MRI REPORT : NO SIGNIFICANT ABNORMALITIES.

Some Special Points:

1. He has lost almost all interest in sports,games,video games,movies and music. He used to do singing but now stopped it completely.
2. He listen to God songs only.
3. He would go to our in-home temple many times a day and join hands. Though it has not been noticed since several months.
4. He always complains that he has no time for friends, society. He says it affects his study but we don't think it does.

Here are the images of his writing :

[image]

[image]

Comment: To me he sounds like an intellectually capable youngster very much in the process of finding himself. Cleverness and introspection are inextricably linked. I wouldn't worry if I were you, just coax him home, gently.

Comment: @Bathsheba He has lost interest in things like games,sports,movies,friends?

Comment: The important thing is that he's at home where you can influence him. He has clearly developed a transient interest in something else, which accounts for his loss of interest in other things. If I were in your position I would lead by example and not pressure him into anything. Talk to him about his new found beliefs.

Comment: @Bathsheba okay. We will do. But the child has been very social,playful but now it seems like he has taken study more important than his life. As far as examples are concered he says Einstein did like this. Feynman did like this. Once I asked him-"If examples from history make sense to him"- he completely denied.

Comment: Oh there's nothing quite like the hubristic black and white dogma of youth! Studying hard is no bad thing for his long term prospects. The most important thing for you is to show you respect him. From the cursory information you've given; to repeat, he seems like a perfectly normal young adult to me, and on the smart side.

Comment: @Bathsheba then its a good news for me